# Trigger on a MenuItem Child - XaML

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

I have done pretty much the same thing as shown in the official documentation of WPF programming. 
`

```
                    <MenuItem.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.Click">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BsB" />
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </MenuItem.Triggers>
                </MenuItem>`
```

The catch being, to make it work under XaML only, no C# involved...
Does anyone have a clue as to why this is not working ?

I have also tried to do it independently :

```
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.Click">
                <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BsB"/>


            </EventTrigger>
```

But I just don't know how to exactly refer to a specific child of a MenuItem. 
I'm sorry if this is a repost, but all that I found wasn't helpful so far, and the MSDN website doesnt exactly show how to do it either.

Thanks